# evaluate $\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{3\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I took a calculus book to check if I am doing integration correctly... I had seen a sum

$$\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{3\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx$$
To evaluate the integration I took $e^\sqrt{x}=y$ hence $e^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm dx=\mathrm dy$
$$=\int \frac{dy}{6}$$
$$=\frac{y}{6}+c$$
$$=\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{6}+c$$

But my book says that the answer is $\dfrac{2}{3}e^{\sqrt{x}}$.. Where did I do mistake?

Comment: You're right to rewrite the integral in the form $\int \frac{dy}{k}$, but $k$ isn't $6$.

Comment: You can also try taking $\sqrt x = t$ and solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure the constants go in the right place, rewrite the equation with dy and dx so it has exactly what appears in the integral.

So multiply by 2 to get $e^{\sqrt{x}}x^{-1/2}dx=2dy$ and then divide by 3 to get $\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{3\sqrt{x}}dx=\frac23dy$. Then finish the substitution.

Answer (score 3):

> $$\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{3\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx$$ To evaluate the
> integration I took $e^\sqrt{x}=y$ hence
> $e^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm dx=\mathrm dy$

So far so good.

$$$$

> $$=\int \frac{dy}{6}$$

But this is wrong, so you've done some silly mistake somewhere here. Let's go back and be careful about each step.

$e^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm dx=\mathrm dy \implies dx = \frac{2\ln(y)}{y} dy$

Then the integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{3\sqrt{x}}\mathrm dx\ =\ \int \frac{y}{3\ln(y)}\ \frac{2\ln(y)}{y}\mathrm dy = \ldots $$

Answer (score 1):

If you do $x=y^2$ and $\mathrm dx=2y\,\mathrm dy$, then $\displaystyle\int\frac{e^{\sqrt x}}{3\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx$ becomes $\displaystyle\int\frac{e^y}{3y}2y\,\mathrm dy$ and\begin{align}\int\frac{e^y}{3y}2y\,\mathrm dy&=\frac23\int e^y\,\mathrm dy\\&=\frac23e^y\\&=\frac23e^{\sqrt x}.\end{align}Your approach is wrong because from $e^{\sqrt x}=y$ and $e^{\sqrt x}\frac12x^{-1/2}\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dy$ you will not get that $\displaystyle\int\frac{e^{\sqrt x}}{3\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{\mathrm dy}6$.